# Could not change string on android app

Tags: android, string, project

I want to change a string on `/res/strings.xml`. I rewrite a new string which name `town` and I can see a new string on the `town.xml` page. I clean the project and run the app but I couldn't see a new string on the emulator, I see old string. What is the problem?

Comment: Have you done this sequence: clean, build, deploy and run? Your are only stating clean & run.

Comment: How can I buil and deploy?

Answer (score 1):

Probably Eclipse fails to overwrite the installed APK on Emulator. 
Remove your app from emulator and try again.

If Eclipse seems unable to reinstall the app in the Emulator, try to restart your Emulator.

This assuming that you have rightly assigned the String in *Town.xml* (with `getResources().getString(R.strings.youreditedstring)` if you assign the String by Java code and not directly in xml)

Answer (score 0):

- Try to manually delete the `/gen/your-package/R.java` file and build/run the app again
- Have you disabled "Build automatically" in the "Project" menu?
- Are you maybe assigning the string in your Java code "manually"?
- Manually delete the app from the emulator (through System Settings --> Applications --> Uninstall) and run it again from Eclipse